# How do I initialize and fill in a list of lists of different lengths?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, python-3.x

I'm writing a small Python program that will simulate a certain TV show (it's for fun guys ok please don't judge me).

In this program, I am trying to randomly sort the contestants into a list of lists (to emulate a Team Challenge, as you may say). I wrote a function that (is intended) to take in an unsorted list of Contestant objects (because I want to access the name attribute of each Contestant object) and a list that contains the information about the sizes of each individual list in the 2D list I intend to return in the end.

To further explain the second parameter, I'll give an example. Let's say the Queens need to be divided into 2 teams of 5 and 6. The numTeams will then be [5,6].

This is full function that I have written so far:

```
    def sortIntoTeams(contest_obj, numTeams):
         # where I will eventually store all the names of the individuals
         queenList = []
         # creates 2D list, however, I just initialized the first subscript
         # part, so to speak
         teamShuffledList = len(numTeams) * [[None]]
         # this was just a test, but I made another for loop to 
         # fill the second subscript part of the 2D list, so to speak too
         for i in range(0, len(numTeams)):
              count = numTeams[i]
              teamShuffledList[i] = count * [0]
         # for loop to fill queenList with all the names of the Queen
         # objects in the contest_obj
         for i in range(0, countRemaining(contest_obj)):
              queenList.append(contest_obj[i].name)
         # from random import shuffle, to shuffle queenList
         shuffle(queenList)
```

Now, what I intend to do is fill the teamShuffledList with queenList, but the teamShuffledList has lists of different lengths. Is there any easy way to keep tracks of the different lengths? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much.

EDIT: Even though it's sorta self-explanatory, the countRemaining(contest_obj) is a different function that I wrote that just counts the remaining contestant objects in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sortIntoTeams(contest_obj, numTeams):
    # Create a randomly-ordered copy of the contestants' names
    random_contestants = [x.name for x in contest_obj]
    random.shuffle(random_contestants)
    result = []
    for teamsize in numTeams:
        # Take the first <teamsize> contestants from the list
        result.append(random_contestants[:teamsize])
        # Remove those contestants, since they now have a team
        random_contestants = random_contestants[teamsize:]
    return result
```

There is no need to "initialize" anything.

Comment: Thank you so much! (Sorry, I'm still an amateur at this)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortIntoTeams(contest_obj, numTeams):
    counter = 0
    teams = []
    for k in numTeams:
        teams.append(contest_obj[counter:counter + k])
        counter = counter + k
    return teams
```